# Does the cp command change file structure?

Tags: cp

I am fairly new to Linux and the Debian distro so please don't beat me up too bad.  My thoughts are that when you use the `cp` command to copy files from drive to drive, it does not change the file structure in any way.  Is that true?  I know that the preserve option will keep permissions, timestamp, etc. but does the `cp` process alter the internal file structure or have the capability in any way to corrupt files?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `cp` can change structure in filesystem, but usually this should not be noticed by programs, so files should never be corrupted. This happens with sparse files: files with a *hole* inside, so in order not to occupy too much space, the filesystem doesn't save the content of the *hole* part.

`cp` has the `--sparse` parameter:

> By  default, sparse SOURCE files are detected by a crude heuristic and the corresponding DEST file is made sparse as well.  That is the behavior selected by `--sparse=auto`.  Specify `--sparse=always` to create a sparse DEST file when‐
>          ever the SOURCE file contains a long enough sequence of zero bytes.  Use `--sparse=never` to inhibit creation of sparse files.

Note: if destination hard-disk is damaged, `cp` could create corrupted files, but never on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

No.  If there is an issue with the connection to one of the drives there is a possibility that corruption could occur during the copy but the `cp` command itself would not cause corruption.  You mentioned permissions and timestamps; those are not stored in the file itself but rather in the metadata.  The `cp` command *can* (and often does) change metadata.

Comment: Note that the metadata also is highly depending on the file system.

Answer (score 0):

`cp` will never *intentionally* corrupt files, but it is of course possible for something to go wrong. For general use, you are not going to have an issue with `cp` for copying files.

If you wish to be certain of the integrity of a copied file, you should check the file hash after copying it, or use a tool with this functionality built-in (such as `rsync --checksum`).

Answer (score 0):

“File structure” is not a precise concept. But for a sensible meaning of the expression, `cp` neither “preserves” nor “changes” the file structure, it *copies* it. The copy will be identical to the original in the manner that `cp` knows to preserve. At a minimum, that means the same file contents, and some identical metadata (permissions, file names and types in a recursive copy, most other metadata such as timestamps with `-p`, etc.). Most implementations of `cp` do not reproduce the internal structure of compressed files such as sparse files. And `cp` will not preserve the file layout (the way the blocks that make up the file are organized on the disk) — this would not be possible within the same filesystem and would not make sense across distinct filesystems. This does not “corrupt” the data since the file contents is preserved: you get the same data, but possibly stored differently.